# How to store and access objects with x,y coordinates by x,y value?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I want to store tiles (50x50 pixel rectangles, and later display them on canvas), but have no idea what data structure should I use.
I need to access it by `x,y` value, and also need to move them by changing the `x,y` value.

a single object would look like this:

```
tile = { x:1, y:2, color:1 }
```

I need hundreds of them.

I've considered simple array, however `tiles[id].x` is the only way to access them, so I need to know the `ID` first, before i can access them `x`.

2D array, seems better, since I can make `tiles[y][x]`, but the values of the `x,y` coordinates where tiles are displayed are not necessarily the same numbers if the coordinates changed. aka: `tile[1][2].x = 1.5` so, accessing the tile at `x = 1.5` become tricky.

Objects in objects essentially the same problem as an array, since it requires to have a key so: `tiles = { tile1:{x:1,y:2,color:1}, tile2:{x:3,y:4,color:2} }` still have no way to access tiles at `x1,y2` without knowing its under `tile1` key.

I know I can use any of the above and `loop` trough them until I find the key, but is it really the only solution?
I've been reading tutorials today about javascript classes, and seems like its somewhat what I need, but haven't found a relevant example.

What would be the best way to store and access a tile's objects by x,y coordinate?

Comment: Do you really have non-integer coordinates? A 2d array sounds like the perfect choice here, especially when there is a tile on every coordinate. Or is your structure only sparsely populated?

Comment: 2d array is fine, until need to move them around, cause than x,y coordinates start to not match  the 2d array position. It can be recalculated each time, but seems error  prone having 2 different coordinate. (one for displaying on  canvas, one is position of array)

Comment: To move it, you would of course move it in the array as well, as otherwise you couldn't look it up by its new position

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want `O(1)` (aka "very fast") lookup time the only option is to use a hashtable with a composed key of `x` and`y`:

```
const map = new Map;

for(const tile of tiles)
  map.set(tile.x + "|" + tile.y, tile);
```

To get the tile at, e.g. x = 5, y = 6 you just do:

```
map.get(5 + "|" + 6)
```

When moving a tile however you also have to move it in the hashtable:

```
function moveTile(tile, toX, toY) {
   map.delete(tile.x + "|" + tile.y);
   tile.x = toX; tile.y = toY;
   map.set(tile.x + "|" + tile.y, tile);
}
```

Comment: Why not a proper `new Map`? Would handle `delete` much better than an object

Answer (score 0):

put all of your tiles in an array, and then use array.filter to get the tile(s) you want. Something like:

```
var tilesFilter = function(x,y) {
  return this.x == 1 && this.y == 2;
}

var tiles = [...];
var myTile = tiles.filter(tilesFilter)[0];
```

Comment: `find` would he more appropriate here

Comment: @JonasW.true, unless you also want to find all tiles in a region, etc...

Comment: Still it has the same issue as the OP stated: "I know I can use any of the above and loop trough them until I find the key, but is it really the only solution?". More concretely, it is slow on large data sets.